# Coroutines And Firebase: How to Implement Javascript-like Promise.all()

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

In Javascript, you can start two (or more) asynchronous tasks simultaneously, wait both of them to finish and then do something/continue:

```
const [firstReturn, secondReturn] = await Promise.all([
    firstPromise,
    secondPromise ];

// Do something with first and second return.
```

What I want to do in Kotlin (Android) is to start downloading two images from Firebase and when both downloads are completed - update the UI with them. So I have two Firebase async functions like this:

```
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference..child("Images/Events/$eventID/eventPhoto.jpeg").getBytes(1024 * 1024).addOnSuccessListener { byteArray ->
                event.image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.size)
            }
//And another one with different path
```

I thought about using Kotlin's "async/await" but since I can't return a value from Firebase function, it didn't work. Is there a straightforward way to do this in Kotlin so I can start to download both images at the same time and do some work after both of them are downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely want to make use of Play services integration with coroutines that's documented [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services).  What you get from this library is an extension function for Task (returned by Play and Firebase async APIs) called `await()` that you can use in a coroutine to defer execution until it's done.

Comment: Hey Doug! Yes, this worked. Thanks a lot for your help.