# How To Use Async/Await/Coroutines In OnCompleteListener Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

I am building a client application which uses Firebase for two things:

- User Authentication
- Using a realtime database

I have managed to set up everything correctly on my client and on my backend server (using Firebase's Admin SDK) and am able to correctly authenticate users and allow them to read/write to the database.

I am also using Retrofit2 to send requests from the client to the backend.

As part of allowing users access to the database, it is needed to send the user's token to the backend so the user can be verified.

To do this, I have the following logic:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    if (user != null) {
        user.getIdToken(false).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                val token = it.result?.token
                //retrofit logic to send request happens from here
            }
       }
```

As you can see, getting the Id token of the user is an asynchronous call and in the current code base that I have, I have this code block for each one of my calls to the backend (duplication).

**I want to know how I can export this snippet to a function (maybe a suspend method?) so that it can be reused for every call to the backend**

I have searched online and have seen many SO questions, but none that fit this scenario.
I have thought about passing in a callback, but I have several methods that communicate to the backend, and each of them will require a different callback method.

The solution I am looking for looks something like this:

```
fun fetchDataFromDB() {
  getIdTokenForUser()
  //wait till it finishes and then
  //perform request to DB
}

fun updateDataInDB() {
  getIdTokenForUser()
  //wait till it finishes and then
  //perform request to DB
}

//......
```

I have tried reading about and implementing coroutines, but I lack the knowledge to do so correctly.

***EDIT***

Thanks to @Doug Stevenson for his answer and direction, I have managed to construct the following:

```
private suspend fun getUserIdToken(user: FirebaseUser) = coroutineScope {

    val job = async {
        user.getIdToken(false).result?.token
    }
    job.await()
}
```

And I use it in this fashion:

```
fun updateDB(context: Context) = runBlocking {

    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    if (user != null) {
        val token = getUserIdToken(user)
    }

  }
```

**Is this the correct approach?** Since the answers given below present a different implementation.

Comment: Based on your comments on my answer, it seems you didn't actually add the `kotlinx-coroutines-play-services` library or import the extension function that I talked about.  There is no need to use `coroutineScope`.  A plain `suspend fun` will work.

Comment: @DougStevenson - On the contrary. I have added the dependency into my build.gradle file, but the import you have in your answer does not exist (as I mentioned in my comment below). When removing to coroutineScope, there is a compilation error on the async keyword.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that you create a coroutine scope everytime you call that function so you don't really get the structured concurrency Roman Elizarov (one of the main contributors of kotlinx-coroutines). My approach is based off of his and you should invoke such suspend function from a lifecycle bound coroutine scope, like `lifecycleScope` in your `Activity` or `Fragment` or `viewModelScope` in any of your `ViewModel` or `AndroidViewModel`. So whenever the lifecycle of the component ends, (onDestroy or onCleared) any pending jobs also cancel and you don't leak the coroutine :)

Comment: Btw @Doug's approach is also correct. He suggests you install a dependency that already performs such wrapping for you on the plain java methods. But in your implementation you create a coroutineScope upon function invokation and that's the bit I think you should change

Answer (score 20):

`getIdToken` is asynchronous returns a Task object.  If you want to use a Task object in a Kotlin coroutine, you can use the library [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services) to add an extension method `await()` to the Task that makes it usable in a coroutine.  With that, you can write something like this:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.9"
```

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await

suspend fun getIdTokenForUser(user: FirebaseUser): GetTokenResult {
    return try {
        user.getIdToken(false).await()
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

You might have to update the types here - I didn't try to compile or test this.

See also:

- [Android kotlin task to be executed using coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269134/android-kotlin-task-to-be-executed-using-coroutines)
- [Coroutines And Firebase: How to Implement Javascript-like Promise.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119804/coroutines-and-firebase-how-to-implement-javascript-like-promise-all)
- [Using Firebase with Kotlin coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562864/using-firebase-with-kotlin-coroutines)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but when I try using your code, I am getting an unresolved reference for the ```await()```. I have imported the coroutine library and from searching online a bit, I see that the code you added might need to be wrapped in ```GlobalScope.async```? I've tried different variations, but still no success.

Comment: You have to import the extension function from the library I linked to in order to use it.

Comment: The link was broken so I fixed it and I still didn't manage to find the import you are referring to. Did you try copying the code snippet you provided inside Android Studio and seeing if it compiles?

Comment: What link was broken?  All the links in my answer work OK for me.  The links to other questions all have similar code and are saying essentially the same thing I'm saying.  The first one even shows the import: `import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await`

Comment: The link you gave for kotlinx-coroutines-play-services was broken. You can see the edit history and see my correction. Furthermore, I am using version 1.3.9 of the dependency and there is no path for the import you have written. There is no tasks package. Await can be found inside of the Deferred interface. I have managed to work out a solution (see the edit to my question).

Comment: If you have a new question, you're supposed to post that separately.  "Is this the most optimal solution" is not what you originally asked.  (It's also seeking opinion, so it would likely get closed as off-topic for Stack Overflow.)  If you want opinion, there are discussion groups that allow for that sort of thing.  If you're simply looking for alternatives, they would appear as additional answers to your original question, prior to the edit.  But honestly, this is how everyone deals with Tasks.

Comment: I understand the rules. I'll edit the question so it is less opinionated and more focused.

Comment: does `await()` with `addOnCompleteListener` and `addOnFailureListener` equivalent to `await()` with just `try/catch` block?

Answer (score 2):

In order to go from a callback based API like the following one:

```kotlin
val myCallback = object : ServiceCallback() {
    override fun onResult(theobject: Something) {
        // your callback code here
    }
    override fun onFailure(ex: Throwable) {
         // error handling
    }

}

theService.enqueue(callback)
```

You can use [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html)

What it does is that it suspends execution until the continuation is satified by the callback. So you can write a KTX like the following:

```kotlin
suspend fun Service.getSomething(): Something = suspendCoroutine{ cont ->
    val callback = object : ServiceCallback(){
         override fun onSuccess(data: Something): Unit = cont.resume(data)
         override fun onFailure(ex: Throwable): Unit = cont.resume(ex)
    }
    this.enqueue(callback)
}
```