# Using Firebase with Kotlin coroutines: Task is not canceled when job is canceled

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

Inside a coroutine, with the help of await() function from "kotlinx-coroutines-play-services" library, i use something like this:

```
suspend fun uploadFile(uri: Uri) = withContext(IO) {
    Firebase.storage.reference.child("example").putFile(uri).await()
}
```

The problem is when the Job of the current coroutine is canceled, this task is not canceled with it and keeps executing.

I need all nested tasks to auto-stop when the job is canceled. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: This `await()` function waits for the operation to complete then it checks if the coroutine is cancelled or not, then continue with result.

Comment: @iamanbansal Is there a way to cancel it when the current coroutine job is canceled?

Comment: so this function is called from the repository but with the `ViewModelScope`?

Comment: @baltekg No. This is to demonstrate the issue I'm facing. The function in repository is a suspend function. I will edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have your `repository` that is is application scoped, so that there is one instance of it in your app.
Let's assume you call your `repository` function from the `ViewModel`. You can use `viewModelScope` to call it from a coroutine that will be lifecycle aware and it will be stopped when the `viewModel` is destroyed.
It could look like this:

```
fun uploadFile(uri: Uri) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    repo.uploadFile(uri)
}
```

And the `repository` function could now look like this:

```
suspend fun uploadFile(uri: Uri) {
    Firebase.storage.reference.child("example").putFile(uri).await()
}
```

If you call it from the `activity` or the `fragment` not `viewModel` you can instead write:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    repo.uploadFile(uri)
}
```

If you have nested calls like the `repository` is called by like a `UseCase` or sth else, you just need to add suspend keyword in every function on the way.

Edit:
You can cancel the `coroutine`, but unfortunately you cannot cancel the `firebase` request. So you want to handle the situation when you cancel the `coroutine` and the file should not be saved remotely. One simple way is to handle it in `onDetach` or sth else in `fragment` or `activity`. One trick you could use is to put you code in the repository in `try` block and add `finally` block. It will be run when the `coroutine` is canceled and there you could check whether file is saved and if so, delete it.

```
suspend fun uploadFile(uri: Uri) {
    try {
        Firebase.storage.reference.child("example").putFile(uri).await()
    } finally {
        // here handle canceled coroutine
    }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html).

Comment: The job is canceled as expected, that's not the problem. The problem is when the job is canceled, the firebase upload task is not canceled with it. It doesn't matter what scope I'm using, after the scope is canceled the task keeps executing and firebase keeps sending the file.

Comment: I edited the answer, take a look, maybe this helps.