# Is there a way to co-ordinate coroutines using on Dispatchers with wait statements across codeblocks

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, blockingqueue, structured-concurrency

I have a situation with a lot of callbacks, specifically onCompleteListeners from Firebase Auth.  First I am getting a Firebase Auth object using an SDK.  However there is no other option but to use an onCompleteListener. Then I need to use another onCompleteListener to get the auth token for it.  I have a use case with a suspend operator function that tries to do a Firebase realtime database call using a REST API.  The problem is my code is getting really ugly.

What would be best would be to do something like you could do with Futures.  I have seen async & await statements in other examples.  What would be best is if I could use something like tags and awaits so I can await on some sections.  If not I can use observers.

Comment: Coroutines way is to almost never use callbacks and generally avoid futures - we use suspend functions instead of them. I don't have a project setup with Firebase right now to check the API, but if you need to perform two operations sequentially, it should be something like: `firebase.operation1().await(); firebase.operation2().await()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64088407/how-to-use-async-await-coroutines-in-oncompletelistener-firebase

Comment: use `suspendCancellableCoroutine{}` to convert Callback/Listener based code into suspendable coroutines